# C++ - isdigit not working properly and causing never ending loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I'm creating a program which converts decimal values into binary values. The issue I'm having is that in my `if` statement I'm checking whether the user input for my `int decimal` variable contains digits before it moves on to converting the values but when it is digits it considers them as alpha characters, which then cause the program to infinitely loop.

When I change `isdigit(decimal)` to `!isdigit(decimal)` the conversion works but if I put in alpha characters it will then infinitely loop again. Am I doing something really silly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

string DecToBin(int decimal)
{
    if (decimal == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    if (decimal == 1) {
        return "1";
    }

    if (decimal % 2 == 0) {
        return DecToBin(decimal/2) + "0";
    }
    else {
        return DecToBin(decimal/2) + "1";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int decimal;
    string binary;

    cout << "Welcome to the Decimal to Binary converter!\n";

    while (true) {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Type a Decimal number you wish to convert:\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> decimal;
        cin.ignore();
        if (isdigit(decimal)) { //Is there an error with my code here?
            binary = DecToBin(decimal);
            cout << binary << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Please enter a number.\n";
        }
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Try going through the code with a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Dev-C++ debugger doesn't give me anything, it successfully compiles and when I do anything that causes the problem it doesn't return anything to me

Comment: I mean trying to step through the code with the debugger line by line, and see what happens; particularly, what the flow of execution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to check for a number in a mixture of number and characters, do not take input into an `int`. Always go with `std::string`

```
int is_num(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int decimal;
    string input;
    string binary;
    cout << "Welcome to the Decimal to Binary converter!\n";
    while (true) {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Type a Decimal number you wish to convert:\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> input;
        cin.ignore();
        if (is_num(input)) { //<-- user defined function
            decimal = atoi(input.c_str()); //<--used C style here
            binary = DecToBin(decimal);
            cout << binary << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Please enter a number.\n";
        }
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

You can always write a function to check for number in a string as shown above. Now your code does not run into an infinite loop. Moreover if you want to take only one valid input and exit the program, u can add a `break`

```
if (is_num(input)) {
    decimal = atoi(input.c_str()); 
    binary = DecToBin(decimal);
    cout << binary << "\n";
    break; //<--
}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you. I will now always take input into a string data type for these sort of scenarios. I kept the `while` loop so the program can be used more than once.